# When should I use 'for update nowait' in cursors?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, oracle10g, database-cursor

In which case do we need to use `for update nowait` in cursors.

Answer (score 36):

Using `for update nowait` will cause the rows to be busy and acquires a lock until a commit or rollback is executed. 
Any other session that tries to acquire a lock will get an Oracle error message like `ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired` instead of waiting the lock to release.

**Session1:**

```
CURSOR abc_cur 
IS 
select * from dept where deptno =10 for update nowait;
```

Here the rows are locked until the cursor is closed or a commit/rollback gets executed.  If, meanwhile, another user from session 2 tries to access the same records then this will throw an error as shown below:

**Session2:**

```
select * from dept where deptno =10 for update nowait;
```

This user cannot even update or delete the same records that have been locked by the first session.

```
ERROR at line 1:
`ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired`
```

**Usage:**
 Now if you want to do some manipulation on certain sets of records and you don't want another user from another session to override your data then you must first lock the records(using `for update nowait`) and then do your manipulation. After you're done with your manipulation, close the cursor and commit.

**EDIT**
Suppose there are 10 rows in temp and I execute the following script in my session 1 :

```
declare
  cursor abc is select * from temp for update nowait;
  temp abc%rowtype;
begin
  open abc;
  -- do slow stuff here
  close abc;
  commit; 
end;
```

In session 2, I execute the following while the script in session 1 is still running

```
select * from temp;

10 rows found
```

If I execute the same script, in session 2, while the script in session 1 is still running

```
declare
  cursor abc is select * from temp for update nowait;
  temp abc%rowtype;
begin
  open abc;
  -- do slow stuff here
  close abc;
  commit; 
end;
```

Then I get `ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired instead of waiting the lock to release.`

Comment: So if i use no wait i cant even fetch(SELECT) the same row from other session, am i right?

Comment: If i want to fetch but not update the same row from another session, how should i handle?

Comment: @user1:yes you can select the same rows from the other session , but you cannout lock the same rows ,if this is been locked by another session .Yes you can fetch the rows from other session .

Comment: My doubt is that, in the case i asked "no wait" cant be used, coz when i use no wait "select" wont work from another session??

Comment: a regular select would work in another session. the rule is that writers never block readers. so a simple "select whatever from table" will work regardless of whether any other sessions have rows locked or not. its just that other sessions will not be able to perform DML on the locked rows until the blocking session commits or rolls back.

Comment: @user1:No, select will work ,if session 1 uses for update nowait .If you try to lock the records in session 2 with for update nowait ,then it will throw you an error .Try it again

Comment: @DazzaL:Right ,as you have asked ,in the first session you use nowait,and in the another session you do a normal select ,which is not working for you ,but that is not possible you can see the records .

Answer (score 11):

Using `for update` **without** the `nowait` clause. will do the following:

- check if the record in question (or records in question) are locked
- if they are locked then wait until they are no longer locked
- lock the records with a new lock that will keep records locked until a `commit` or `rollback` is executed.

Using `for update` **with** the `nowait` clause. will do the following:

- check if the record in question (or records in question) are locked
- if they are locked then do not wait, but **exit with an error message**
- if the records are not locked then lock the records with a new lock that will keep records locked until a `commit` or `rollback` is executed.

The examples in the previous answer would also work if session 1 gets a lock `for update` **without** the `nowait` clause, while session 2 uses the `nowait` clause.

Hope that helps.